# ngClass with multiple/different statements

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend

I looked through similar questions but coudn't wrap my head around the solution I am looking for.

So basically I have this piece of code:

```
 <div class="attendees-list__item-order-status course-details-attendees text text-cooler-grey align-self-center pl-3"
          [ngClass]="
            heading === 'Abrechenbare Buchungen' ? 'col-md-4' : ' col-md-3'
          "
        >
          {{ attendee?.lastName }}, {{ attendee?.firstName }}
        </div>
```

I would like to modify and add an extra statement. The logic will be if (`heading === 'Abrechenbare Buchungen'` or if `heading === 'Kürzlich abgerechnete Buchungen'`) and `attendee?.orderStatus == 'CANCELLED'`, then it should add the class `'text--line-through'` to both `col-md-3` and `col-md-4`.

I tried with `"||"` as I saw in other simialr questions but could't find a working solution, I wasn't writing the syntax correctly most probably.

Comment: _I tried with `"||"` as I saw in other simialr questions but could't find a working solution, I wasn't writing the syntax correctly most probably._  Could you expand on this?  It would be helpful to see what exactly you tried and understand in what way it didn't work for you.

Comment: Try using the class.className version like `[class.text--line-through]="heading === 'whatever' || heading === 'otherstuff'"` to add that extra className independent from your ngClass condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular best practices says that evit add logic in your HTML. move it to Ts.

Add in your ts a getter:

```
  get useColFour() {
    return (
      (this.heading === 'Abrechenbare Buchungen' ||
        this.heading === 'Kürzlich abgerechnete Buchungen') &&
      this.attendee['orderStatus'] == 'CANCELLED'
    );
  }
```

change your html:

```
<div class="attendees-list__item-order-status course-details-attendees text text-cooler-grey align-self-center pl-3"
          [ngClass]="useColFour ? 'col-md-4' : ' col-md-3'
          "
        >
          {{ attendee?.lastName }}, {{ attendee?.firstName }}
        </div>
```

Comment: Should I add the class text--line-through in the html template?

Comment: yes. make something like this: [ngClass]="{'col-md-4': useColFour, 'col-md-3': !useColFour }"

Comment: but if u  have a long list of clases. u can make the object in yout ts. and binding it in your html. TS:   public class = { 'col-md-4': this.useColFour, 'col-md-3': !this.useColFour }; in HTML:   [ngClass]="class"

Answer (score 1):

There's another way of declaring class. Like that:

```
<div
    class="attendees-list__item-order-status course-details-attendees text text-cooler-grey align-self-center pl-3"
    [ngClass]="heading === 'Abrechenbare Buchungen' ? 'col-md-4' : ' col-md-3'"
    [class.text--line-through]="(heading === 'Abrechenbare Buchungen' || heading === 'Kürzlich abgerechnete Buchungen') && attendee?.orderStatus == 'CANCELLED'">
  {{ attendee?.lastName }}, {{ attendee?.firstName }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this html template is linked to an actual component, I'd suggest to create a method in the component  that return the class, and just use it in your "ngClass" directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep it in the markup:

```html
[ngClass]="{'col-md-4': heading === 'Abrechenbare Buchungen', 'col-md-3': heading !== 'Abrechenbare Buchungen', 'text--line-through': attendee?.orderStatus == 'CANCELLED'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function like this that will be good instead of messing up HTML

```
 <input type="text"  [class]="getAgeTextColor(form.get('ActiveAge').value)" class="form-control-plaintext" [ngClass]="{'form-control-plaintext': true}" formControlName="ActiveAge">

getAgeTextColor(ActiveAge){
  if(ActiveAge != null){
    const months = ActiveAge.split(' ')[0];
    if(months >= 24){
      return 'text-green';
    }else if(months > 12 && months < 24){
      return 'text-yellow';
    }else if(months <= 12){
      return 'text-red';
    }
  }else{
    return '';
  }
}
```